# "Maybe I will go and race in something else" VS "Maybe I go and race in something else"

Tags: grammar

I was wondering whether it would be possible to use second term?
I know first term is correct but does it mean the second one is not correct?

Comment: The second example is wrong as you suspect. It needs a modal verb before *go*.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe I will go and race in something else

This sentence is generally correct. In almost all situations this is what you would use.

> Maybe I go and race in something else

This is for when you are talking about a hypothetical case, while removing the emphasis on your own actions. Think about a mafia boss making vague threats:

> It's fine if you don't pay your protection money. But maybe I find myself in need of funds one day, what will I do then?

As a general rule though, you need the modal verb in your first sentence.